# Spring boot security with 3 fields authentication and custom login form

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

I'm using spring boot and i need to implement spring security with 3 fields authentication process username, password and corporate identifier as a hidden input in a form.

I implemented a custom usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter but it not seems to be enough to setup the security config.

EDIT :

Users don't seem to be authenticated ! because a can access to authenticated request defined in web config

EDIT 2 :

in my custom filter when a enter a valid user it's do execute on succesfulAuthentication. What i'm missing please provide me any help :(
Here were i am

```
@Repository
public class AuthenticationUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationUserDetailsService.class);

@Autowired
private UserRepository users;

private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User userdetails;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String input) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println(input);
    String[] split = input.split(":");
    if (split.length < 2) {
        LOGGER.debug("User did not enter both username and corporate domain.");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("no corporate identifier is specified");
    }
    String username = split[0];
    String corporateId = split[1];

    System.out.println("Username = " + username);
    System.out.println("Corporate identifier = " + corporateId);

    boolean enabled = true;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    com.ubleam.corporate.server.model.User user;

    user = checkUserDetail(username, corporateId);

    if (user == null)
        throw new NotAuthorizedException("Your are not allowed to access to this resource");

    LOGGER.info("User email : " + user.getEmail() + "#User corporate : " + user.getCorporateId());

    userdetails = new User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, getAuthorities("ROLE_USER"));
    return userdetails;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param roles
 *            roles granted for user
 * @return List of granted authorities
 * 
 */

public List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(String roles) {

    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(roles));
    return authList;
}

/**
 * User authentication details from database
 * 
 * @param username
 *            to use for authentication
 * @param coporateId
 *            corporate identifier of user
 * @return found user in database
 */
private com.ubleam.corporate.server.model.User checkUserDetail(String username, String corporateId) {

    com.ubleam.corporate.server.model.User user = users.findByEmailAndCorporateId(username, corporateId);

    return user;
}
```

My custom filter :

```
public class PlatformAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PlatformAuthenticationFilter.class);

private static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL = "{0}/bleamcards/{1}/home";
private static final String LOGIN_ERROR_URL = "{0}/bleamcards/{1}/login?error";
private String parameter = "corporateId";
private String delimiter = ":";
private String corporateId;

@Override
protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String username = request.getParameter(getUsernameParameter());
    String extraInput = request.getParameter(getParameter());

    String combinedUsername = username + getDelimiter() + extraInput;

    setCorporateId(extraInput);
    LOGGER.info("Combined username = " + combinedUsername);
    return combinedUsername;
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
    String url = MessageFormat.format(LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL, contextPath, corporateId);

    response.sendRedirect(url);
}

@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
    String url = MessageFormat.format(LOGIN_ERROR_URL, contextPath, corporateId);

    response.sendRedirect(url);
}

public String getParameter() {
    return parameter;
}

public void setParameter(String corporateId) {
    this.parameter = corporateId;
}

public String getDelimiter() {
    return delimiter;
}

public void setDelimiter(String delimiter) {
    this.delimiter = delimiter;
}

public String getCorporateId() {
    return corporateId;
}

public void setCorporateId(String corporateId) {
    this.corporateId = corporateId;
}
}
```

And finally the web security config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Inject
private AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth;
@Inject
private UserDetailsService userDS;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/bleamcards/**/login", "/bleamcards/**/forgetpassword", "/bleamcards/**/register", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/webjars/**")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.eraseCredentials(false);
    auth.userDetailsService(userDS).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());

}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return auth.build();
}

@Bean
public PlatformAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    PlatformAuthenticationFilter authFilter = new PlatformAuthenticationFilter();
    authFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
    authFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    authFilter.setUsernameParameter("username");
    authFilter.setPasswordParameter("password");
    authFilter.setParameter("corporateId");
    return authFilter;
}

@Override
protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return userDS;
}
```

I want users to be able to connect only to /login /register /forgetpasswod urls for their respective corporate platforms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually i manage to find a solution to my issue.

I added successHandler on successfulAuthentication was missing ! And a failureHandler too on unsuccessfulAuthentication methods.

Here is my new Authentication filter :

```
public class TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

private static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL = "{0}/bleamcards/{1}/home"; 
private static final String LOGIN_ERROR_URL = "{0}/bleamcards/{1}/login?error";
private String parameter = "corporateId";
private String delimiter = ":";
private String corporateId;


@Override
protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String username = request.getParameter(getUsernameParameter());
    String extraInput = request.getParameter(getParameter());
    String combinedUsername = username + getDelimiter() + extraInput;

    setCorporateId(extraInput);
    System.out.println("Combined username = " + combinedUsername);
    return combinedUsername;
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain , Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
    String url = MessageFormat.format(LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL, contextPath, corporateId);
    setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler(url));
    super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);

}

@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
    String url = MessageFormat.format(LOGIN_ERROR_URL, contextPath, corporateId);
    setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler(url));

    super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
}

public String getParameter() {
    return parameter;
}

public void setParameter(String corporateId) {
    this.parameter = corporateId;
}

public String getDelimiter() {
    return delimiter;
}

public void setDelimiter(String delimiter) {
    this.delimiter = delimiter;
}

public String getCorporateId() {
    return corporateId;
}

public void setCorporateId(String corporateId) {
    this.corporateId = corporateId;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you check that your `AuthenticationUserDetailsService` code is actually been executed? If the framework is not invoking it this means that your configuration is not properly hooking that `UserDetailsService`. In your `WebSecurityConfig` I think you need to have this:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean(); //not return auth.build();
}
```

I suggest you to take a look at [this](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/tree/spring_security_extension_webmvc/extensions/spring/stormpath-spring-boot-starter-spring-security) branch from [Stormpath](http://www.stormpath.com). There, they are configuring Spring Boot to use a custom [AuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html) (similar to an `UserDetailsService`). That module uses and depends on [this other Spring Security module](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/tree/spring_security_extension_webmvc/extensions/spring/stormpath-spring-security).

Then, [this sample Spring Security Example](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/tree/spring_security_extension_webmvc/examples/spring-security-webmvc) (note that it is not Spring Boot, but just Spring) will give you a complete example of the way the [Spring Security Java Config](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/blob/spring_security_extension_webmvc/examples/spring-security-webmvc/src/main/java/tutorial/SpringSecurityWebAppConfig.java) is done. Please note that this Java Config extends [this one](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/blob/spring_security_extension_webmvc/extensions/spring/stormpath-spring-security-webmvc/src/main/java/com/stormpath/spring/config/StormpathWebSecurityConfiguration.java) which actually hides much of the actual internal configuration.

Disclaimer, I am an active Stormpath contributor.

Comment: Why return actually change it for a call for a super class @jstack ?

Comment: With that line we are not only running the parent authenticationManagerBean method, we are also exposing the authentication Manager as a Bean.